# Scheme "mcar: contract violation"

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (create-polygon ptlist)
  (if (null? ptlist) 0
      (append (list (make-seg (car ptlist) (cadr ptlist))) (create-polygon (cdr ptlist)))))
```

My problem is whenever I try to run this program it gives contract violation error. I know that you can't car or cdr empty lists but I'm checking if it's empty or not. So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
(define lst '(1))

(null? lst)
=> #f

(cadr lst)
=> cadr: contract violation
```

As you can see, the contract violation occurs because `(null? lst)` only checks whether the list is currently empty. But if you use `cadr`, which is `(car (cdr lst))`, then you have to check whether `(cdr lst)` is empty as well.

So, your if statement needs to check both `(null? ptlist)` and `(null? (cdr ptlist))`, preferrably using `cond`.